# Flash/Flex/HTML: if I store Adobe's TLF text format in database, will it be difficult to change later when porting app to HTML?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, tlf

I have a Flex-based web application that must accept rich text input from the user. Adobe's [TLF format](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/formats/TextLayoutFormat.html)  would work here.

But since the application will eventually port to HTML, what options are there to replace the TLF formatted text stored in my database to something compatible in the HTML world? I'm worried about future compatibility.

Alternatively, what options do I have for my Flex application to store rich text in my database in something other than Adobe's TLF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although many of the features are similar to ones possible with HTML and CSS, there is not 1 to 1 compatibility. The most compatible format will be HTML, much like what WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE produce.